# springboot 2.1.2 log4j2 log files are not created

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

Hi I am new to springboot I was trying to generate logs in file but not able to do so,Please help me in this.
All the logs coming into console files are not cretaed why application starts there is whitelabel error 500 from thyme leaf.Db connections are created and tables are created,but logs are not generated.
[image]
log4j2.properties

```
status = trace
name= properties_configuration

# Give directory path where log files should get stored
property.basePath = C:/logs/

# ConsoleAppender will print logs on console
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = consoleLogger
appender.console.target = SYSTEM_OUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout

# Specify the pattern of the logs
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%t] [%c] [%M] [%l] - %msg%n


# RollingFileAppender will print logs in file which can be rotated based on time or size
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = fileLogger
appender.rolling.fileName= ${basePath}app.log
appender.rolling.filePattern= ${basePath}app_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.zip
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%t] [%c] [%M] [%l] - %msg%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies

# Rotate log file each day and keep 30 days worth
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.basePath = ${basePath}
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.maxDepth = 1
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified
# Delete files older than 30 days
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.age = 30d

# Mention package name here in place of example. Classes in this package or subpackages will use ConsoleAppender and RollingFileAppender for logging         
logger.name = com.optq.main.optimizeq
logger.com.optq.main.optimizeq.level = trace
logger.com.optq.main.optimizeq.additivity = trace
logger.com.optq.main.optimizeq.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger
logger.com.optq.main.optimizeq.appenderRef.console.ref = consoleLogger

# Configure root logger for logging error logs in classes which are in package other than above specified package
rootLogger.level = trace
rootLogger.additivity = trace
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = consoleLogger
```

Comment: do you have the spring-boot-starter-log4j2 as dependency? Please take a look at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-actuator-log4j2 for a working example

Comment: What is your pom.xml? spring boot by default have slf4j but not log4j2. You need to exclude slf4j dependency and include log4j2 dependency. You can use both also if you want.

Comment: yes i have spring-boot-starter-log4j2 and excluded 
spring-boot-starter-logging

Comment: @ThinkTank okay. The issue is with ${basePath}. You basepath is present in property.basePath. If I am not wrong, you need to give full property name like ${property.basePath} instead of ${basePath} to refer to other properties in the file.

Comment: Also, check the application start up logs whether your log4j2.properties is getting picked automatically or not.

Comment: Yes ${property.basePath} but no good
and logs 
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/shailesh.singh/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/shailesh.singh/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.11.1/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.11.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.